# Prevent integer overflow by scaling input

Tags: integer-overflow

i do have a question regarding integer overflow prevention.

Lets consider the following variables:

```
uint32_t a;
uint8_t b;
```

Constraints:

- only integer arithmetics
- no 64bit variables
- b <= 2

The following calculation may produce an overflow:

```
uint32_t c = a*b;
```

From what i see, i have the following possible solutions the problem:

1. saturate the result from the multiplication to uint32_MAX
2. restrict the input of `a` to maximum value of (uint32_MAX / 2)
3. divide `a` by a specific factor (for example by 2) to prevent an overflow within the multiplication. I could save the factor and use it later in the calculation to reobtain the correct value.

**What is a good way to solve this problem?**

At the moment i am inclined to use option 3. This would ensure i have the maximum possible accuracy up to a certain threshold, while still allowing me to execute the calculation at all (though i am loosing accuracy for bigger integer values.

**Are there any downsides to option 3?**

Best regards,
plusminus

Comment: If you are able to save the factor and use it later, why can't you just save b and use it later instead?  It is essentially the same as the factor you would use, since it is at most 2.  What platform is this?  If you have access to CPU arithmetic flags, you could potentially treat your result as a 33-bit number by using the overflow flag.